# Dispatch click eventon JSDOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to use JavaScript events to check an input checkbox in JSDOM.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" />
```

But I can't seem to get it to check itself by dispatching an event on it:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", false, true);
document.querySelector('#foo').dispatchEvent(evt)
```

However, it does work when I use jQuery's `.trigger('click')`

Why doesn't this code work in jsdom? I feel there's some minor inconsistency in jsdom and likely some other browser which jQuery fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a browser dependency on the way you can manually trigger events in JavaScript.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mc8f3/).

**The Code:**

```
document.getElementById("foo").value='500';
if (document.getElementById("foo").fireEvent) {
    document.getElementById("foo").fireEvent("onclick");
} else if (document.getElementById("foo").dispatchEvent) {
    var clickevent=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    clickevent.initEvent("click", true, true);
    document.getElementById("foo").dispatchEvent(clickevent);
}
```

---

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mc8f3/1/)

**Updated Code:**

```
if (document.getElementById("foo").fireEvent) {
    document.getElementById('car-make').attachEvent('onchange', update);
    document.getElementById("foo").fireEvent("onchange");

} else if (document.getElementById("foo").dispatchEvent) {
    document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('change', update, false);
    var clickevent=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    clickevent.initEvent("change", true, true);
    document.getElementById("foo").dispatchEvent(clickevent);
}
function update () {
    alert('changed');
}
```

Comment: I can dispatch a click event just fine, however, I can't dispatch a change events. Can you modify the fiddle to dispatch a change event?

Comment: Just change `click` to `change` at one place & `onclick` to `onchange` at another and you should be good to go. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: In your updated fiddle, the checkbox still does not check. Which event is required to check the box?

Comment: Ok. If you trigger the `click` event like in my first fiddle & listen to the `change` event in my second fiddle then the checkbox gets checked and also triggers the `change` event. [**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mc8f3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

From [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value **has been** modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.
>
> - Bubbles: Yes
> - Cancelable: No
> - Context Info: None

Note how this is different from the `click` event, for example:

> The click event occurs when the pointing device button **is** clicked over an element.

Thus, triggering a `change` event will not actually change the input value.

Loosely speaking, the `Cancelable: No` property says that nothing will happen by default.